# Update multiple UILabel/UIButton font sizes by constant value

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, font-size

I want to be able to increase/decrease the size of **several** the label/button fonts on my storyboard by the same amount. As far as I know sizes can be changed when selected (though as labels or buttons separately) and adjusted but each is updated by one font value not say a percentage. Ideally I'd like to select all labels and buttons and enter a value to times them by (e.g 1.4x). Is there definitely no way of doing this?

Comment: What difficulty are you facing to change the font size of your labels or buttons?

Comment: To increase/decrease them proportionally I'm required to manually adjust each label/button by a fixed size - as opposed to one operation changing them simultaneously.

Comment: Do you have some idea of auto layouts and size classes?

Comment: Yes but I've read nothing about font. If I'm missing something important please let me know.

Comment: This is a good tutorial to start with.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started
 Just follow along this tutorial. You will learn how to use size classes to make the fonts adaptable.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, I will go through it. If you give that as an answer I can tick it.

Comment: Sure. And if there's any ambiguity don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I've read through that guide and others now, and they've helped. But I'm now stuck on resizing UIButtons - they don't have the autoshrink option under Attributes inspector and no combination of the following (in viewDidLoad) works:                                                                                                        buttonShare.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1, 
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true, 
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

Comment: Great but the titleLabel of a button won't resize the button. Now that you have the basic idea of auto layouts, I encourage you to position the buttons and labels relatively and use appropriate constraints that would resize buttons as the layout changes. Lastly, can you tell more about your layout maybe that can help because without knowing that I'm not in a position to give any suggestions.

Comment: That makes sense about the titleLabel not working. What would I put in its place? At the moment the labels are resizing but not the buttons, which I can't downsize through code once they truncate. Along with various other constraints I'm using aspect ratio from labels to the superview and labels to a dummy view (centred in the middle) to make them proportional in font size (with autoshrink) and spacing respectively, across different size classes. You've been a great help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the label multipliers to create percentage view sizes and auto shrink to resize the text to be proportionally sized.